# google maps address autocomplete in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am trying to implement `Google Maps` Address Autocomplete in `ASP.Net MVC` application. `Google` example is taken from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

It works fine and easy in `html` file, but when I try to implement it in `MVC` view - drop-down address box is not showing up. My Google key is included in `API` reference and data packages are seen in Chrome "Network" tab.

I was researching this for a lot of time and have tried different approaches - no success for now. For example, I've tried to include scripts in "scripts" @section - not successful also.

I can see `div` with a class `"pac-container"` after "`scripts`" tag, but for some reason the style "display: none" not removes when I type address, as it does in `html` file:

[image]

I am using `Visual Studio 2015` `MVC5` template. `MVC` view source is here:

```
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
        #locationField, #controls {
            position: relative;
            width: 480px;
        }

        #autocomplete {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 99%;
        }

        .label {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100px;
            color: #303030;
        }

        #address {
            border: 1px solid #000090;
            background-color: #f0f0ff;
            width: 480px;
            padding-right: 2px;
        }

            #address td {
                font-size: 10pt;
            }

        .field {
            width: 99%;
        }

        .slimField {
            width: 80px;
        }

        .wideField {
            width: 200px;
        }

        #locationField {
            height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
    </style>

    <p>My Aaddress Autocomplete Example</p>
    <div id="locationField">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
               onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Street address</td>
            <td class="slimField">
                <input class="field" id="street_number"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
                <input class="field" id="route"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">City</td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
                <input class="field" id="locality"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">State</td>
            <td class="slimField">
                <input class="field"
                       id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
            <td class="label">Zip code</td>
            <td class="wideField">
                <input class="field" id="postal_code"
                       disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Country</td>
            <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
                <input class="field"
                       id="country" disabled="true"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer></script>
```

Comment: `key=MY_KEY=places` is it a typo? It should be `key=MY_KEY&libraries=places`. Also, did you enable a Places API Web Service in your project?

Comment: Hi, xomena! Thanks for your reply. Yes it was a typo - coping the source here, it the project it is fine. I have found the cause of the problem and fixed it. It was caused by broken settings in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the problem and fixed it. It was caused by broken settings in Visual Studio.